# Why we use sleep command before xset dpms?

Tags: command-line, suspend, display, xserver, standby

I have the following line to turn my laptop display off:

```
sleep 1 && xset dpms force standby
```

`sleep 1`: Puts the thread to sleep for 1 second.

`xset dpms force standby`: From [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/xset.1.html), forces the dpms flag to standby.

When I omit the `sleep 1` command, the `xset` command puts the pc in standby mode for 1 second, then automatically resumes normal operation. But when combined with `sleep 1` command, it puts the pc in standby mode indefinitely, until a user input has been detected.

Can you explain the relationship between these two commands and why it works this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run your command, two events happens, "KeyPress" and "KeyRelease".

So when you run this command with pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> button.

```
xset dpms force standby
```

First a "KeyPress" happens, it will cause the command to immediately be run and puts the monitor to sleep, when you release the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, then "KeyRelease" happens and it's a user activity so monitor comes back to working.

If you do the job really fast (Hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and realsing it before command being run) your monitor stays at "sleep" state.

---

To test this things, install `x11-xserver-utils` package.

```
sudo apt install x11-xserver-utils
```

then run `xev`.

Now hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see whats happens; you should see something more or less like:

```
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
...

KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2600001,
...
```

---

So we use `sleep` to make sure both this events happens before command being run.

Comment: You're right. When hitting enter key fast, the display stays off. So `sleep 1` is to make sure xset does not register keyrelease upon hitting enter key.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think its probably to do with what the system considers to be "user activity".

If the system detects keyboard activity it comes back from sleep.  That fact that you press *enter* to send the force standby command counts as some "current" activity and so it immediately un-sleeps.

sleep 1   ensures that the keyboard has not recorded activity for 1 second before the sleep command is sent, so standby goes ahead.

Comment: There are potentially  2 human activity events occurring as you press the enter key.
key down  ,
  comand run  ,  key up.   
If you exagerate the delay in key up you always see the screen come back.