# Suspend to RAM not working

Tags: drivers, kernel, suspend, 20.10

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** **Today, Supermicro answered officially to my inquiry. The *X11SPA* supports neither suspend to ram nor suspend to disk. In my opinion, this is a substantial flaw, since that motherboard is their flagship for workstation-oriented applications. Be aware of it.**

Ubuntu 20.10 here, first installation upon a newly built system. Everything works perfectly except one thing that's very important to me: **suspend2ram**.

If I try to suspend (sleep) via `systemctl suspend`, the screen blanks out, but nothing else happens, power stays on, fans spinning. At this point, if I press the power button, the monitor turns on, and all is how I left it.

Look at this now. On my system:

```
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
[s2idle]
```

Whereas upon a laptop where suspend **works**, it is:

```
$ cat /sys/power/mem_sleep
s2idle [deep]
```

How can I debug the issue? Surely, there is some device which prevents suspend, but how to find it?

What follows are:

1. `inxi` dump to show you the system config.
2. relevant `syslog` dump.

EDIT1: Tried hibernation. The system resumes with corrupted screen, then hangs and requires hard reset.

EDIT2: Installed windows10, s2ram not allowed. Hibernation hangs more or less the same way.

```
System:    Host: bliz Kernel: 5.8.0-26-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.19.5 
           tk: Qt 5.14.2 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM Distro: Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla) 
Machine:   Mobo: Supermicro model: X11SPA-TF v: 1.01 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 3.3 
           date: 02/21/2020 
Memory:    RAM: total: 125.44 GiB used: 1.94 GiB (1.5%) 
           RAM Report: permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required. 
CPU:       Info: 24-Core model: Intel Xeon Platinum 8260M bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Cascade Lake rev: 5 
           L2 cache: 33.0 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 220800 
           Speed: 1000 MHz min/max: 1000/3900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1204 2: 1001 3: 1000 4: 1167 5: 1001 6: 1000 
           7: 1088 8: 1200 9: 1504 10: 1000 11: 1200 12: 1049 13: 1146 14: 1000 15: 1100 16: 1000 17: 1098 18: 1036 
           19: 1000 20: 1141 21: 1113 22: 1341 23: 1041 24: 1143 25: 1000 26: 1089 27: 1000 28: 1043 29: 1001 30: 1141 
           31: 1087 32: 1001 33: 1086 34: 1200 35: 1101 36: 1307 37: 1001 38: 1177 39: 1070 40: 1000 41: 1017 42: 1001 
           43: 1089 44: 1056 45: 1000 46: 1086 47: 1001 48: 1099 
Graphics:  Device-1: ASPEED Graphics Family vendor: Super Micro driver: ast v: kernel bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 1a03:2000 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER] driver: nvidia v: 455.28 bus ID: 19:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f06 
           Device-3: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER] driver: nvidia v: 455.28 bus ID: 1a:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f06 
           Device-4: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER] driver: nvidia v: 455.28 bus ID: 65:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f06 
           Device-5: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER] driver: nvidia v: 455.28 bus ID: b4:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1f06 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz s-dpi: 101 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 455.28 direct render: Yes 
Network:   Device-1: Intel I210 Gigabit Network vendor: Super Micro driver: igb v: 5.6.0-k port: 2000 bus ID: 05:00.0 
           chip ID: 8086:1533 
           IF: eno1 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:25:90:be:43:2d 
           Device-2: Aquantia AQC107 NBase-T/IEEE 802.3bz Ethernet [AQtion] vendor: Super Micro driver: atlantic v: kernel 
           port: 2000 bus ID: 06:00.0 chip ID: 1d6a:07b1 
           IF: eth0 state: down mac: 00:25:90:be:43:f5 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 11.38 GiB (2.4%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 PRO 512GB size: 476.94 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 287.37 GiB used: 11.37 GiB (4.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 180.06 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p3 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 62 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 29% 
Info:      Processes: 752 Uptime: 2m Init: systemd v: 246 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 alt: 10 Packages: apt: 2979 
           Shell: Bash v: 5.0.17 running in: konsole inxi: 3.1.07
```

```
Nov  7 17:50:25 bliz systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz ModemManager[1471]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767908.1255] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767908.1256] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:51:48] offline
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz kernel: [  995.921939] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz systemd-sleep[3346]: Suspending system...
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz kernel: [  995.928295] Filesystems sync: 0.006 seconds
Nov  7 17:51:48 bliz acpid: client 1788[0:0] has disconnected
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [  996.340713] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [  996.343045] OOM killer disabled.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [  996.343046] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [  996.344199] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [  996.346322] serial 00:04: disabled
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [  996.346577] serial 00:03: disabled
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883067] pci 0000:16:05.0: disabled boot interrupts on device [8086:2034]
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883157] pci 0000:64:05.0: disabled boot interrupts on device [8086:2034]
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883192] pci 0000:b2:05.0: disabled boot interrupts on device [8086:2034]
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883581] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883584] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883594] usb usb5: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883597] usb usb6: root hub lost power or was reset
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.883940] power_meter ACPI000D:00: Found ACPI power meter.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.885528] serial 00:03: activated
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.886870] serial 00:04: activated
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.943776] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1016.972019] nvme nvme0: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.212955] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214100] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214135] ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214177] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214222] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214266] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214312] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.214368] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.392324] usb 1-1.2: reset low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1017.751867] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1018.749136] fbcon: Taking over console
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1018.749140] OOM killer enabled.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1018.749141] Restarting tasks ... 
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1018.751194] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1018.751614] done.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz kernel: [ 1018.754898] PM: suspend exit
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz acpid: client 1788[0:0] has disconnected
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz pipewire[2335]: #033[1;33m[W][000000998.421004][main-loop.c:157 pw_main_loop_run()] main-loop 0x55fa059cc0a0: iterate error -4 (Interrupted system call)#033[0m
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz systemd-sleep[3346]: System resumed.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz acpid: client 1788[0:0] has disconnected
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz pipewire[2341]: #033[1;33m[W][000000998.421027][main-loop.c:157 pw_main_loop_run()] main-loop 0x55eacc699e10: iterate error -4 (Interrupted system call)#033[0m
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz acpid: client 1788[0:0] has disconnected
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz ModemManager[1471]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767930.9755] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767930.9757] device (eno1): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767930.9928] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767930.9929] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed bound -> done
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.7 on eno1.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.7.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Interface eno1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b8ff:d7cb:f7bb:ca99 on eno1.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address fe80::b8ff:d7cb:f7bb:ca99.
Nov  7 17:52:10 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Interface eno1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767931.0036] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767931.0329] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767931.0341] device (eth0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767931.0369] device (eno1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz dbus-daemon[1287]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=1289 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz dbus-daemon[1287]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz nm-dispatcher[3625]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon: No such file or directory
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767931.0651] device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: client connected from 1788[0:0]
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: client connected from 1788[0:0]
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: client connected from 1788[0:0]
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: client connected from 1788[0:0]
Nov  7 17:52:11 bliz acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov  7 17:52:13 bliz ModemManager[1471]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.6/0000:05:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz kernel: [ 1021.957276] igb 0000:05:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz kernel: [ 1022.063973] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2455] device (eno1): carrier: link connected
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2459] device (eno1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2475] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (da1d0e20-bea3-38af-9caf-d380db64c81e)
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2485] device (eno1): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (da1d0e20-bea3-38af-9caf-d380db64c81e)
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2487] device (eno1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2494] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2499] device (eno1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2509] device (eno1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2513] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv6 with address fe80::b8ff:d7cb:f7bb:ca99.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: New relevant interface eno1.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Registering new address record for fe80::b8ff:d7cb:f7bb:ca99 on eno1.*.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2811] dhcp4 (eno1): option dhcp_lease_time      => '21600'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2811] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name          => 'homenet.telecomitalia.it'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2811] dhcp4 (eno1): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2811] dhcp4 (eno1): option expiry               => '1604789534'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.7'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eno1.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.7.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2812] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: New relevant interface eno1.IPv4 for mDNS.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz avahi-daemon[1283]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.7 on eno1.IPv4.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_routers    => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2813] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2814] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2814] dhcp4 (eno1): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2814] dhcp4 (eno1): option routers              => '192.168.1.1'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2814] dhcp4 (eno1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2814] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2836] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2858] device (eno1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2860] device (eno1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2865] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2875] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2876] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2953] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Nov  7 17:52:14 bliz NetworkManager[1289]: <info>  [1604767934.2965] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz systemd-resolved[1264]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz whoopsie[2263]: [17:52:16] online
Nov  7 17:52:16 bliz dbus-daemon[2340]: [session uid=1000 pid=2340] Activating service name='org.kde.KSplash' requested by ':1.98' (uid=1000 pid=3707 comm="/usr/bin/kwin_x11 --crashes 1 " label="unconfined")
Nov  7 17:52:24 bliz systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Nov  7 17:52:29 bliz systemd-resolved[1264]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

Comment: I guess your EDIT should become the accepted answer, is that correct?

Comment: Right. Done....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supermicro answered officially to my inquiry. The X11SPA supports **neither** *suspend to ram* (ACPI S3) **nor** *suspend to disk* (ACPI S4). In my opinion, this is a substantial flaw, since that motherboard is their flagship for workstation-oriented applications. Be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the output off:

```
sudo s2ram -n
```

To see if your config is recognized.
If it is not recognized please edit:

```
/etc/powersave/sleep
```

And try:

```
SUSPEND2RAM_FORCE=yes
```

From this page: http://powersave.sourceforge.net/powersave/Suspend2Ram.html
You can also try:

> Just add them to your "kernel"-line in /boot/grub/menu.lst. More information about those can be found in /usr/src/linux/Documentation/power/video.txt.

> You can try the following:
>
> ```
> * acpi_sleep=s3_bios
> calls the video BIOS during resume to initialize the video card.
> * acpi_sleep=s3_mode
> calls the video BIOS during resume to reset the text mode.
> * acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode
> combines the above.
> ```

> Also if it "just does not work", it may be a good idea to try with the kernel parameter "vga=normal", which will give you a simple text console during boot (sorry, no fancy graphics for this one). You need to remove the existing "vga=0x317"

Another possibility is that you're hibernating, not suspending, and something goes wrong.

I see you have 128 GB of RAM and 180 GB of swap. That's a lot, so I guess you're using it when you attempt to suspend/hibernate.
For hibernating you need at least the same amount of memory in use, free on the swap.
That should not be a problem unless when you try to hibernate when there is in use an amount of RAM + swap, that is bigger than the free swap.
For example, if you was using 120GB of RAM plus 70 GB of swap from the NVMe, that's 190GB, and your swap is 180 GB so in that situation crash is guaranteed.

Please, check the logs like this:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "kill\|time\|hang\|panic"
dmesg -T | grep -i "kill\|time\|hang\|panic"
```

There are situations in which the system is busy (for example with IO or swapping) and the system cannot suspend.
Do you use iSCSI volumes as guest?.

Update:
You can enable traces by suspending by running as root an script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sync
echo 1 > /sys/power/pm_trace
echo mem > /sys/power/state
```

This explanations and more come from here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/s2ram.html

You can check dmesg with:

```
dmesg -T | less
```

Comment: There is no `sram` command on my systems, nor `apt` offers suggestions about its installation. Also, there is no `/etc/powersave/` directory. Also, note that the directions from the page you linked are for problems during resume from suspend to ram, but in my case the system refuses to suspend outright. Hibernation: all my hibernation attempts have been made with the swap partition completely unused.

Comment: Sorry, typo, s2ram. You can also enable traces. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/s2ram.html

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl `sleep 1 && xset dpms force standby` might work for S2RAM.
Found it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914503/why-we-use-sleep-command-before-xset-dpms).

Comment: Tried it. Same outcome: the screen blanks out, nothing else happens. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions
If your suspend is failing, and a # tail /var/log/acpid shows "Permission denied" errors, be sure that your new ACPI event and action scripts have the appropriate permissions.

Write error
If # echo mem > /sys/power/state shows "write error: Operation not permitted", verify that CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU option is enabled in the kernel. Suspend2 automatically selects this option.

Broken sysfs interface
You may experience problems when using # echo standby > /sys/power/state or # echo mem > /sys/power/state (machine goes to sleep and wakes up immediately). This can be avoided by using # echo -n 3 >/proc/acpi/sleep to get it to sleep. This can be also happen if hotplug daemon is still running or if the usb hcd modules are still loaded.

Immediate Resume after Suspend
If a resume starts a few seconds after suspend a reason might be the USB modules. Unload the modules uhci_hcd and ehci_hcd before you suspend. Users of hibernate-scripts add "UnloadModules uhci_hcd ehci_hcd" to /etc/hibernate/common.conf.

Hangs on "switching to UP code"
You may be using a frequency scaling governor such as "conservative" or "ondemand", which sometimes have problems with suspending. Switching to a governor such as "powersave" or "performance" before suspending may solve this problem.

MySQL daemon running
If you're running MySQL, sleep may also not work, so stop MySQL first, then sleep. Remember to restart MySQL when you wakeup.

LCD backlight remains on during sleep
When your system is equiped with a Radeon Mobility graphic controller your LCD backlight may not turn off automatically. Use radeontool to switch off your backlight prior suspend in your sleep action script.

High power drain during sleep
Also, you might want to take note of the Problem with high power drain in ACPI sleep.

SD cards must be unmounted
On current (10.x) and past versions of Ubuntu, the system will fail to suspend (black screen, blinking "moon") if an SD card is mounted. Use the script at the Aspire One community page in order to safely work around this. On other systems, you may be able to simply add "sdhci mmc_block mmc_core" to the MODULES= line in acpi-support.
Or try this (pm-utils & pci-sd):
Add the follwing line to the # /etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module to unload the module before standby:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES sdhci"
```

Comment: Nothing of the above worked. Also, I have no sd cards, no mysql, and no /proc/acpi/sleep file.
Guys, I tried to install windows and it doesn't suspend either. So the problem is probably less linux-specific.

Comment: I... fine sorry i just copied and pasted it in from another websie